Cloud foundry java cap application error pushing
I'm new in this world, and I'm trying to deploy a cap java application to my cloud foundry trial env. The java application is compile by jdk sap machine 17, but when I try to push to cf I receive an error. Here manifest.yml:
applications:
  - name: bookshop
    random-route: true
    path: srv/target/bookshop.jar
    memory: 1024M
    buildpacks:
      - sap_java_buildpack_jakarta
    env:
      JBP_CONFIG_COMPONENTS: '{ "jres": ["com.sap.xs.java.buildpack.jre.SAPMachineJRE"] }'
      JBP_CONFIG_SAP_MACHINE_JDK: '{ "version": "17.+" }'
      JBP_CONFIG_TOMCAT: '{"tomcat": {"version": "10.+"}}'

below the error:
Configuration from /tmp/buildpacks/0f4bb749499a5a5e/config/sap_machine_jre.yml modified with: {version: 17.+}
SAP Java Buildpack Version: 2.21.0
Downloaded 'SAP Machine JDK', version '17.0.13_0.0.b0' in 1.835 s.
SEVERE: Unhandled exception in Buildpack main method: None of the available runtimes [Tomee7, Tomcat, Java Main] supports the application in the specified path.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: None of the available runtimes [Tomee7, Tomcat, Java Main] supports the application in the specified path.
at com.sap.xs.java.buildpack.Buildpack.lambda$detectComponent$5(Buildpack.java:268)
I tried with a lot of buildpacks but I never figure out! Can anybody help me, thanks!
